# How do the contents of this NSArray look in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsarray

I know how to create an array in swift, simply

```
var arr = ["Foo", "Bar"]
```

but I am not sure how I can transform this to swift:

```
NSArray *coachMarks = @[
    @{
        @"rect": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:(CGRect){{0,0},{45,45}}],
        @"caption": @"Helpful navigation menu"
    }
];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: It's an array with one dictionary (of so far Strings to AnyObject). What are you wondering about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to store dictionaries in array, this is step by step process how to achieve that:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
let dict1 = ["rect": NSValue(CGRect: rect)]
let dict2 = ["caption": "Helpful navigation menu"]
let array: [AnyObject] = [dict1, dict2]
```

Edited:
Sorry I inserted two dictionaries to array but in your question you have just one, this is corrected answer:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
let dict1 = ["rect": NSValue(CGRect: rect), "caption": "Helpful navigation menu"]
let array: [AnyObject] = [dict1]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was struggling last night. It's a dictionary, after all!

Answer (score 1):

it would look something like this

```
var coachMarks: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = [["rect": NSValue(CGRect: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 45.0, 45.0)),
"caption": "Helpful navigation menu"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
var coachMarks : [AnyObject] = [ ["rect" : NSValue(rect: NSRect(origin: CGPointMake(0, 0), size: CGSizeMake(45, 45))), "caption" : "Helpful navigation menu"]]
```